# drupal 7 function call by jquery Ajax with out using hook_menu

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7, and I need a ajax request communicate with a function mentioned in a   node/page. I am trying to do it with out using hook_menu(). But ajax is not communicating with   specified node.

Created a page called "test/star" and in body of the page i wrote  and i defined test_example() function in my .module. But it is not working. Please anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without hook_menu()?

Comment: Actually our project is migrated from d6 to d7. In d6, we used custom modules and hook_menu. But in d7, we were asked not to use hook_menu(). Why it is not working with node? Is the only way is to use hook_menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can use menu hooks to create AJAX pages in Drupal 7.

If you cannot get the AJAX page to work, make sure you've cleared Drupal's cache via the admin menu, or via drush, using `drush cc all`.

Here's an example that I've just verified against my Drupal 7 installation. I've created a module, and I've added a implementation of hook_menu():

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  // Simple AJAX callback
  $items['ajax/testing'] = array(
    'title' => 'Get a list of foobar',
    'file' => 'includes/foobar.inc',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_get_foobar',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And in includes/foobar.inc:

```
function mymodule_get_foobar() {
  $data = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
  return drupal_json_output($data);
}
```